# The intersection of all conjugates of a subgroup is of index at most $n!$

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups, normal-subgroups

> Show that if $H$ is a subgroup of a group $G$ of index $n$, then the normal subgroup
> $$
> N:=\bigcap_{g \in G} g H g^{-1} \subseteq G
> $$
> has index $\leq n!$.

This is an exercise of my algebra course.

I know that the conjugacy class of $H$ has $[G:N_G(H)]\leq n$ elements and $[G:H_1\cap H_2]\leq [G:H_1][G:H_2]$, which is not enough. I have no idea how to proceed. Any hint is welcomed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

In fact $N$ is known as the [core](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Core_(group_theory)#:%7E:text=The%20normal%20core,-Definition&text=More%20generally%2C%20the%20core%20of,subgroup%20is%20the%20subgroup%20itself.) (or normal core) of $H$. Your claim can be proven by constructing an appropriate isomorphism, and appealing to the first isomorphism theorem, as follows:

Note that $G$ acts on elements of $G/H$ by left multiplication; in other words, for each $g\in G$, we have the bijection $\varphi_g:G/H\rightarrow G/H$ defined by $\varphi_g(xH):=(gx)H$. We therefore have the group ismomorphism $\Phi:G\rightarrow S_{G/H}$ defined by $\Phi(g):=\varphi_g$ (where $S_{G/H}$ is the group of permutations on $G/H$). We have the following chain of equivalences

\begin{equation}
\begin{split}
g\in\ker(\Phi)&\iff \varphi_g=\text{id}\\
&\iff gxH=xH\text{ for all }x\in G\\
&\iff x^{-1}gxH=H\text{ for all }x\in G\\
&\iff x^{-1}gx\in H\text{ for all }x\in G\\
&\iff g\in xHx^{-1}\text{ for all }x\in G\\
&\iff g\in N\\
\end{split}
\end{equation}

and thus $N=\ker(\Phi)$. By the first isomorphism theorem, we have that

$$\text{Im}(\Phi)\cong G/\ker(\Phi)=G/N$$

and thus

$$[G:N]=|\text{Im}(\Phi)|\leq |S_{G/H}|=[G:H]!$$

as desired.

Comment: Nice classical answer. Adding to your answer, some permutations of $G/H$ need not be of the form $\phi_g$. For example transposition: $(H,yH)$ implies $H \rightarrow yH = gH$ and $yH \rightarrow H = gyH$. This implies $g^2 H = H$ and hence we need $g \notin H$ and $g^2 \in H$. if $H$ is cyclic of order co-prime to $2$ then $g \notin H$ and $g^2 \in H$ is impossible.

Answer (score 0):

This is the *normal core*. It's the largest normal subgroup contained in $H$.

It's easy to show that it's the kernel of the homomorphism induced by the action of $G$ by left multiplication on the cosets $G/H$.

Thus it's the kernel of a homomorphism into $S_n$, and the result follows.